# Bousfield-Kan Formula for Homotopy Limits

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\Lambda$ and $C$ be categories, with $\Lambda$ small and $C$ complete. Let $F : \Lambda \rightarrow C$ be a diagram, where $C$ is cotensored over simplicial sets; there is then a functor $[\Delta^{op}, \text{Set}]^{op} \times C \rightarrow C$, written $(X, a) \mapsto a^X$. We can form the end $\int_{\lambda} F(\lambda)^{N(\lambda/\Lambda)}$.

1. How can we view $C = \text{Top}$ as having a map $[\Delta^{op}, \text{Set}]^{op} \times C \rightarrow C$? That is, what is the typical way to do this? I was thinking to use that $\text{Top}$ is cotensored over itself, and then to use the realization map.
2. How can we view $C = \text{Grpd}$, the category of small groupoids, as having a map $[\Delta^{op}, \text{Set}]^{op} \times C \rightarrow C$. I was thinking to use that $\text{Grpd}$ is cotensored over itself, and to use the realization map induced by the covariant functor $\Delta \rightarrow \text{Grpd}$ sending $[n]$ to the contractible groupoid with $n+1$ elements.
3. Under what conditions is this limit the same as the homotopy limit of $F$ in $C$? Does $C$ have to be a quillen category for this to be true?

Comment: 3. Under the assumptions in your question it's not clear what else the homotopy limit would even mean. To get any other notion you'd better at least have some weak equivalences in your category. You have the right idea for 1. and 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So if it has weak equivalences, then this matches the derived functor of lim under certain conditions? If you turned your comment into an answer I would gladly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simplicial model category, for instance, your formula always defines a right derived functor of limit, so agrees with the "global" definition of homotopy limit.